# How to get the list of images stored in firebase storage in a website?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

To import the data from firebase storage into android, we use 'Snapshot'.

Similarly, how do I import a list of images or data into a **website** by 'javascript' or 'PHP'? In the firebase documentation( https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files ), there is a way to download a single image. I want to show the data in a listview on website.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about getting the URL of multiple images you have stored in Firebase Storage.

There is currently **no** way to list all the items you've stored in Firebase Storage with the Storage API.

One way to list all the items you have stored would be to create a Firestore database and save all the URLs in the database.
This way you can index all the URLs with

```
dbref.collection('collection').get()
```

For more information: [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)